# Ubuntu installation from external hard drive does not detect my computer hard drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I'm trying to make my computer dual boot Windows/Ubuntu.
I made an external hard drive bootable from Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS iso file.

Now I'm trying to install Ubuntu following [this tutorial](https://www.lifewire.com/ultimate-windows-8-1-ubuntu-dual-boot-guide-2200654) but when it comes to the "Installation type", the Dual Boot option is not displayed.

I tried installing with the "Something else" option but it actually detects the partitions of my external hard drive, not the computer hard drive.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: What brand/model computer? UEFI or BIOS boot install? If you have Windows you want to install in same boot mode. Is Windows fast start up still on? http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Dell xps 15 9560, UEFI and I dont know about the fast start-up statut, probably on as I didn't switch anything related

Comment: I turned off fast start up but the dual boot option is still not there and my computer hard drive partitions are still not detected. I also have this dialog box before the "Installation type" step : https://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Force-UEFI-Installation.jpeg

Comment: Dell normally has drives set to RAID, and they need to be AHCI, but you must install AHCI drivers into Windows first. Dell XPS 13 9560 install without issues
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2357321 & 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_15_9560 While slightly different models, issues are common across multiple Dell. Dell UEFI Dual boot instructions using Something Else
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-a-recent-windows-operating-system-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=EN You may need to update UEFI and SSD firmware also.